# What is the reference/context of the statement in the whatsapp presentation?

Tags: united-states, ukraine

In a recent [whatsapp presentation](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7491627/Ukraines-president-trolls-world-leaders-spoof-WhatsApp-group.html) from Volodymyr Zelensky at the 16th annual Yalta European Strategy which was a hilarious take on global state of affairs. The one which i wanted to understand is at one point USA writes

> You are such a beautiful lady…

and then delete and write

> Sorry, wrong chat.

What is the context of that? Why was it mentioned and then deleted, is there any political gimmick or stunt behind that statement?

Comment: It's a question about a presentation by a national leader. How is that not a question about politics? Comes under "3. Conflicting Egos" as on-topic in the help centre surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an allusion to Trump's history with women. He was [involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormy_Daniels%E2%80%93Donald_Trump_scandal) in a scandal with a porn star etc.

At the end of the chat there's a "selfies" moment and USA posts Trump's photo, so the "USA" is basically identified with him personally.